Outlook is not opening in another system, implemented in C++, MFC framework
I am working on a project, in this project I am add a feature, if I click on a button then it will open the outlook and send a file to another user. in my system the build is working fine, version of the outlook is 2010.
In another system the feature is not working. if he clicked on the button then an error message is coming
it saying: NO Such interface supported. in his system version of the outlook is 2021.
//This is the code what i have done
void CWeavesView::OnSendButton()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to initialize COM library."));
        return;
    }

    // Create an Outlook application instance
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spOutlookApp;
    hr = spOutlookApp.CoCreateInstance(L"Outlook.Application");
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to create Outlook application instance. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }

    // Get the MAPI namespace
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spNamespace;
    VARIANT vtEmpty;
    VariantInit(&vtEmpty);
    hr = InvokeMethod(spOutlookApp, L"GetNamespace", &vtEmpty, 1, 
    CComVariant(L"MAPI"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to get MAPI namespace. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }
    spNamespace = vtEmpty.pdispVal;

    // Create a new mail item
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spMailItem;
    hr = InvokeMethod(spOutlookApp, L"CreateItem", &vtEmpty, 1, 
    CComVariant(0)); // 0 = olMailItem
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to create mail item. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }
    spMailItem = vtEmpty.pdispVal;

    // Set the subject
    CComVariant vtSubject(L"Subject of the email");
    hr = PutProperty(spMailItem, L"Subject", &vtSubject);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
         CString errorMsg;
         _com_error err(hr);
         errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to set subject. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
         AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
    }

    // Set the body
    CComVariant vtBody(L"Body of the email");
    hr = PutProperty(spMailItem, L"Body", &vtBody);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to set body. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
    }

    // Attach the file
    CComPtr<IDispatch> spAttachments;
    hr = GetProperty(spMailItem, L"Attachments", &spAttachments);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to get attachments collection. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
        CoUninitialize();
        return;
    }
    CString file_path_Name = _T("F:\\1.TIS");
    CComVariant varFilePath(file_path_Name);
    hr = InvokeMethod(spAttachments, L"Add", &vtEmpty, 1, varFilePath);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to attach file. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
    }

    // Display the email
    hr = InvokeMethod(spMailItem, L"Display", nullptr, 0);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        CString errorMsg;
        _com_error err(hr);
        errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to display email. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
        AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
    }

    // Cleanup
    CoUninitialize();

}


Most probably the newer Outlook doesn't support automation. In any case, it is very old approach to try to send e-mail today via Outlook which is likely not anymore used in home users. The best thing to do is to use a REST API of an existing well known service like gmail, or at the end, implement SMTP given a known SMTP server, username+password and port.

Okay, I understand this, but is there any other method to do that this thing. @MichaelChourdakis

In which part of your program do you see the error message?

@MichaelChourdakis Authentication is a horrendous mess, though. It either requires that you take a dependency on some (buggy) WebView component, or implement a good chunk of a web browser yourself.

@IInspectable you mean using REST or by reimplementing SMTP yourself? it's not trivial but it's doable.

@MichaelChourdakis For REST, since REST ultimately means OAuth. Good luck getting your token without a browser.

@IInspectable, yes, but you can start the browser for authentication and create a small web listening to a localhost:port in which the 'code' is returned to you.

Exactly what I said: You cannot avoid taking a dependency on (or writing) a browser. And if you aren't prepared to write a browser you now have to deploy your application using any one of a handful of shitty installer technologies.

You won't write a browser, you will open the authentication URL with ShellExecute and wait for the code to be returned at your end. At least that's what I 'm doing and it works for many APIS, including google drive, one drive, tiktok and YouTube upload.

Right, and pray that your application's dependencies are resolved at the clients' ends. Doesn't read like a sustainable engineering strategy.

@AlanBirtles
CComPtr spMailItem;
hr = InvokeMethod(spOutlookApp, L"CreateItem", &vtEmpty, 1, 
CComVariant(0)); // 0 = olMailItem
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    CString errorMsg;
    _com_error err(hr);
    errorMsg.Format(_T("Failed to create mail item. Error: %s"), err.ErrorMessage());
    AfxMessageBox(errorMsg);
    CoUninitialize();
    return;
} 

at this part i am facing issue with newr version
